# Loop neither looping nor breaking while reading from a file

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

I have been having a strange issue. My loop suddenly ceases to loop and will also not break. It reads fine for the first several items and just suddenly stops.

I have the following loop to read from a file:

```
while ((tmpChar = in.read()) != -1) { //While we have not reached the end.
  System.out.println("looped");
  buffer[j] = tmpChar;
  // If this byte is a capital letter.
  if (buffer[j] > 64 && buffer[j] < 91) {
    // We make it lower-case.
    buffer[j] += 32;
  }
  if (buffer[j] != 39 && (buffer[j] < 96 || buffer[j] > 122) && (buffer[j] < 48 || buffer[j] > 56)) {
    // Otherwise, if byte is not an apostrophe, not a letter and
    // not a number.
    if (j > 0) {
      // Word is completed, let's "tokenize".
      words.insert(new String(buffer, 0, j));
      System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, j));
    }
    j = 0;
  } else
    j++;
}
System.out.println("broke");
```

Comment: `in` is probably an `InputStream`? And what is the declaration of `tmpChar`?

Comment: My guess is the declaration of the while loop itself. try while ((tmpChar = in.readLine()) != null).

Comment: You need to provide more code if you want someone to come up with a solution. There is a nested loop in the code which you do not show. Please give the extra code so somone can give a solution

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I didn't check back! I've been really busy! It turned out that my reading was fine, the error occurred in my RedBlackTree insert method.

 words.insert(new String(buffer, 0, j)); << Right here. I just fixed the insert method in the ADT and everything worked out just fine.